# How to Create API Signature with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlencode

First attempt at connecting to a Bitcoin exchange's private API and I am already stuck in trying to do a Test call with my code.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from urllib import urlencode
import datetime

api_key = "myAPIkey"
api_secret = "mySercetKey"

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
values = urlencode({"timestamp" : timestamp})

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "key": api_key, "sig": api_secret}
request = Request("https://www.fybsg.com/api/SGD/test", data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

Here's what was returned from response_body:

```
{"error":"An unexpected error occurred, its probably your fault, go read the docs."}
```

Can a kind soul point out what's wrong with my code? (I've got a feeling it's seriously wrong)
The API documentation for the bitcoin exchange can be found [here](http://docs.fyb.apiary.io/). (Test function)

Comment: According to the documentation, the `sig` should be a `HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with Key's Secret`, and I don't see any hashing happening in your code.

Comment: Tanveer, your advice helped! response_body is now returning {"error":"Invalid Signature!"} instead after inputting my real api key and secret. Guess I will have to contact the exchange for further advise.

Comment: Hi Rawing, good point. That's probably the reason why I getting a "invalid signature" response now. Any recommended links to read up on how to produce a HMAC-SHA1 signature?

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert in cryptography to know any good links. Google/Wikipedia to the rescue I suppose.

Comment: @JChan I have tried to make `HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with Key's Secret` as mentioned in the API Doc. Hope it works.

Comment: @Tanveer Are you able to post a sample of the `HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with Key's Secret` you created? I would greatly appreciate if you can! Still tearing my hair out over this over here =(

Comment: @JChan I'm getting the `hashed_value` in this format `KHMhHf8mSZ6Kv0o0aTwrQ8H/I/w=`. You have to confirm whether the `hashed = hmac.new(values, api_secret, sha1)` is correct means I have given `values` and `api_secret` as argument to `hamc` function. So are those arguments right or it is expecting some other arguments as per the API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were passing invalid **timestamp**, in the API documentation they have mentioned that the `timestamp`   have to be `Current Unix timestamp` which can be achieved like this:-

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = int(time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple()))
```

OR just:

```
import time
timestamp= int(time.time())
```

---

So after updating your code

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from urllib import urlencode
import datetime
import time

api_key = "myAPIkey"
api_secret = "mySercetKey"


timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()               #.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
timestamp = int(time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple()))
print timestamp
values = urlencode({"timestamp" : timestamp})

#sig - HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with Key's Secret
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
hashed = hmac.new(values, api_secret, sha1)
hashed_value = hashed.digest().encode("base64").rstrip('\n')

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
           "key": api_key, "sig":hashed_value}
request = Request("https://www.fybsg.com/api/SGD/test", data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

I'm getting this response:-

```
{"error":"Invalid API Key or account number"}
```

Which I think you can fix by using your valid `private key` or `account number`.

Comment: Or just use `import time; timestamp= time.time()`.